# auto update table using ajax and json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So, i've been trying to find a solution for my problem, but since i'm not advanced user in jquery/ajax, maybe i'm looking for the wrong thing, so i hope someone can help me.

---

#### Objective

My main objective is to build an 'order table' and i want this table to update and insert a new entry when the DataBase has a new incoming order. Without the need of a page refresh. So every time a new order is made on the website by the client, the admin table insert a row with it's data on the top of the table.

---

#### What i have

Right now i'm using **AJAX** to call the **JSON** file with all the information. The **JSON** file is being write using **PHP** code. There is no problem with the **JSON/PHP**, i can write/update the file when a new entry is made, i don't need to run any scripts manually, etc..

---

#### CODE

This is the code i have so far:

AJAX to load JSON and write the data on the table=

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/results.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function (response){
        var write;
        $.each (response, function (index, table) {
            write += '<tr><td>' + table.name + '</td><td>' + table.data + '</td>';
            if (table.status === true) {
                write += '<td class="ap">Aprovado</td>'; 
            } else {
                write += '<td class="ng">Negado</td>';
            }
            write += '<td>' + table.id + '</td><td><button class="bt_delete">Deletar</button></td></tr>';
        }); //end each
        $('#mytable').html(write);
    }); //end getJSON
});
```

I trie dto use this code to update the table, but it doesn't work. I do have the console log, but the table doesn't update:

```
var $container = $("#mytable");
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container;
    console.log("loaded");
}, 10000);
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Quick! Quick! Go check DataTables http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html, it looks like you don't know it and you're trying to develop it yourself. It handles all this stuff for you.

Comment: @JeremyThille IIRC DataTables doesn't have built in features for auto-requesting an update from the server. Celsom would have to call `table.ajax.url('..').load()` within the `setInterval`.

Comment: As for why your table isn't rewriting itself with your code you're simply creating a variable that contains your table, you're not overwriting it. Create a function that handles your `.getJSON` and writing the table rows and call that function in your `setInterval`.

Comment: Well, i did tried datatables, but didn't found anything about the auto refresh option, i even tried to look on their forum, and found nothing. Like i said, i'm new to advanced things in jquery/ajax, maybe i was looking for something different. But i also want to build it myself because it's a complete admin dashboard and i'll use for different projects. Also, i want to add a 'notification' system with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setInterval()` isn't actually doing anything with `container` other than assigning it to `$('#mytable')` which is why you're getting the `console.log()` but nothing else.

See the snippet below.

```js
function buildTable() {

  var url = "data/results.json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    var write;
    $.each(response, function(index, table) {
      write += '<tr><td>' + table.name + '</td><td>' + table.data + '</td>';
      if (table.status === true) {
        write += '<td class="ap">Aprovado</td>';
      } else {
        write += '<td class="ng">Negado</td>';
      }
      write += '<td>' + table.id + '</td><td><button class="bt_delete">Deletar</button></td></tr>';
    }); //end each
    $('#mytable').html(write);
  }); //end getJSON

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var refresh = setInterval(function() {
    buildTable();
  }, 10000);
});
```

### Edit

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/jjq2rzzg/) with a demo showing the `buidTable()` function appending to the table rather than recreating it.

```js
var isFirst = true;
var refresh = setInterval(function() {
    buildTable(isFirst);
    isFirst = false;
}, 10000);

function buildTable(isFirst) {
        
    if ( isFirst ) {
        // Old code goes here for the first time it is ran.
    } else {
        // Append to the table instead of building it.
        // Change row to be that of your json data source from .getJSON()
        var row = "<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>";
        $('.table > tbody').append(row);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ok, now i'm on the way =D But is there a way to make it more dynamic? Instead of rewrite the whole table, just add the line with a slide animation? Also, is this the best way to do what i'm trying to do? Or can i run the function only when the JSON is updated?

Comment: Instead of `.html(write)` try `.append(write)`. It won't give you an animation but it will insert a new `<tr>` at the end of the table. With an animation it would be a bit more complicated. As for the 'best way to do it' there's a hundred different ways to do any given task sometimes you just have to go with what works when you're learning and improve on it from there.

Comment: I was trying to do it, but it's appending the whole table again and again. I did a if condition to do it only if the last id in my JSON is greater than the id on the page, but when it loads, it load everything back again. Do you know any fix?

Comment: I tried your code, but with the same result, it's loading everything again. Maybe i did something wrong.. So i made this jsfiddle with my own code i'm using right now. http://jsfiddle.net/y4jsx05p/ (i don't know how to load an external json file in jsfiddle).

Comment: @CelsomTrindade I think it has something to do with your `lastLoaded` and `updateMyId`. I commented that out and it started running and calling the script, appending the json to the table.